# Bind the doctrine ORM entity and doctrine ODM document and use it in SonataAdminBundle

Tags: mongodb, symfony, doctrine-orm, sonata-admin, doctrine-odm

I have a User entity and Address document. They are linked between each other with @gedmo\references doctrine extension. This relation works just fine. I can get both referenceMany and referenceOne linked objects.

Now i need to use it at the sonataUserBundle form to let user to add multiple addresses for the user. (user - in mysql, address - in mongodb).

I tried to use this in the userAdmin class:

```
  $formMapper->add('addresses', 'sonata_type_model', array(                    
                'class' => 'Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Document\Address',
                'required' => false,
                'expanded' => true,
                'multiple' => true
            ))
```

it gives me an error:

```
No entity manager defined for class Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Document\Address
```

Please, answer what should I do!

Comment: It seems that Sonata and gedmo\references don't work tegether just like that. 
check this issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24391982/sonata-and-gedmo-references-doctrine-extension-doesnt-work-class-does-not-exi     and   try this bundle: https://github.com/prestaconcept/PrestaSonataGedmoDoctrineExtensionsBundle

Comment: Have you tested the PrestaConcept bundle with Doctrine Extension Reference usage @tiriana ? I'm not sure if this is implemented that's why I asked for it: https://github.com/prestaconcept/PrestaSonataGedmoDoctrineExtensionsBundle/issues/6

Comment: No, I have not, sorry. I haven't even try gedmo references. I only found some info and pasted a link. So unfortunately I cannot help.

Comment: FYI @nicolas-bastien stated that the project is no longer maintained: https://github.com/prestaconcept/PrestaSonataGedmoDoctrineExtensionsBundle/issues/6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get that error because a ModelManager of an Admin Class only supports the **manager_type** that you configured which is the **ORM** default. So it is looking for an entityManager.

I have a similar case but the other way around. Inside my Document Admin Class I have to link to an Entity. It works this way:

```
$formMapper->add('user', 'entity', array(
                'class'    => 'ApplicationSonataUserBundle:User',
                'label' => 'User'
            ));
```

You should simply be able to use **entity** and **document** as type instead of **sonata_type_model**.

Comment: Thanks for your answer it helps me too, but I still have a little bug is that when I update/create my entity this error appears : notice : Array to string conversion